# execute POST requests in the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I have array with data (objects):

```
var data = [
    {"name":"Jon",
    "age":22},
    {"name":"Ioan",
    "age":42},
    {"name":"Jem",
    "age":33},
    ... other more then 100 items
    ]

    var http = require('http');

    var options = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 80,
        path: '/users',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        } };

    //I create following function:
function sendData(data) {
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            });

        });
        req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        req.end();
}

//end try send for each array item:
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
   sendData(data[i]);
}
```

But sended only first item from array.

How I can send each item as POST request?

May be the best solution may suggest.

If requests will execute as async it will be better.

**UPDATE:**

I find better solution with async module.
Add following code:

```
var async = require("async"); 
var tasks = [];

for (i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
    tasks.push(sendRequest(data[i]));
}

async.parallel(tasks, function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

And all request wat sended async.

Comment: You can send the complete JSON object (`data`) to the server and parse it there. Saves you a couple of hundred requests. Which server side language are you using?

Comment: I can't change code on server. Server handle only following data: {"name":"Jon",
    "age":22}

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?

If so you can use the `$.post` method along with a `$.each` method.

You could do something like

```
$.each(data, function(index, val) {
    JSON.stringify(val);
    $.post(url, val)
     .done(function (data) {
         alert("got " + data + " back");
    });
});
```

Not the most concise, but it'll do the trick, and it'll do it asynchronously.

full dox here:

[for $.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

[for $.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: No, i write on nodejs, its small console application.

Comment: @Gene You can install jQuery on node.js. Might be useful. [Here's how to install it.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery)

Comment: Thx, but I find solution without jquery.